# Is there anything to help me create a sortable table (with search filters)?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going over my old system and updating the old, deprecated code from mysql to PDO and just giving it a general makeover. The system basically grabs data from the database, displays it in a fancy table and its then sortable by clicking on the table headers or by changing the search filters by the side. (e.g having a drop down box of different categories)

It's been a right nightmare updating the old system because the code is just all over the place. It currently gets the search filters information from the URL via GET and dynamically creates a query string. This makes it even more complicated when working with prepared statements.

Is there anything out there that can help me avoid a headache? I'm looking for something that allows me to display information from a database and also has the options to add search filters. I could probably build one from scratch but I just don't want to waste the effort on something that has (probably) already been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like using datatables. It can process large datasets very quickly and all of that sorting you talked about is a feature with datatables.

https://datatables.net/

Comment: Just the thing I was looking for! Thanks!